# Restricting access to all files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

For some reason, only the index.php file in my directory is being restricted, even though I am using the following directives in the .htaccess file:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "Administration"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

Any idea why only the index.php page is being restricted?  I can access any other file in the directory without an authentication window.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you enter password for index.php and other windows won't ask for password again?

Comment: I go to the index.php page and it asks for the password.  I don't enter it yet.  I then go to a different page or file and it does not ask for the password.  So I never authenticated at any time, yet, I'm still able to access all files except index.php.

Comment: Are those the only directives in your .htaccess-file?

Answer (score 0):

Every file is being restricted in that directory. It's the way the .htaccess-file works.

> The .htaccess file affects the directory in which it is placed, so any visitor requesting any page/file within that directory would be presented with an authentication request.

I suspect that what undone has said in the above comment, is true. Once you enter the username/password combination for any file in that directory, you have access to all files within the directory.

If you would like to password-protect only a single page (or a few), you can add the following directive to your .htaccess-file:

```
<Files "mypage.html">
  require valid-user
</Files>
```

That way, only the mypage.html-file would require a password.

You would, however, need to remove the `Require valid-user`-statement already in your file.

Comment: Even if I close my browser and reopen it and go first to any file not named index.php, I can access it with no problem or password needed.  If I then go to index.php, a password is asked for.

Comment: Then there have to be other directives in the .htaccess-file... (or the .htaccess-file from the above directory). Could you provide them?

Comment: That's my only thought, but I could not find any other htaccess files outside of that directory.  Maybe I should look in the apache config files?